# Error al insertar una imagen en una página php

Tags: php, php7

Tengo la siguiente página php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

     <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />
    <title>prueba</title>
    

</head>
<body>

                <h2><mark><em>La octava ingresa al inframundo</em></mark></h2>
                <figure>
                    
                    <img src="C:\Users\wapg2\OneDrive\Escritorio\curso HTML5\Imágenes de las páginas web\Octava.jpeg"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        
                        Miembros de la octava compañía de fuerzas especiales de bomberos

                    </figcaption>

                </figure>

</body>




</html>
```

leyendo sobre la instrucción include en php leí lo siguiente: "Cuando un archivo es incluido, el intérprete abandona el modo PHP e ingresa al modo HTML al comienzo del archivo objetivo y se reanuda de nuevo al final. Por esta razón, cualquier código al interior del archivo objetivo que deba ser ejecutado como código PHP, tendrá que ser encerrado dentro de etiquetas válidas de comienzo y terminación de PHP.", según lo que entendí el archivo objetivo es el archivo que vamos a incluir, por eso pensé que hacer lo siguiente en otra página php estaría bien

```
<?php
   
    include 'DatosShinraYArthur.php';
    
?>
```

cuando corro la página php en el navegador casi toda la página se muestra bien a excepción de las imágenes que inserte, ya que estas no se muestran.

Comment: Prueba a poner la imagen en otra ubicación que no sea OneDrive

Comment: no me funcionó :(

Comment: El problema debe ser con **la ruta de las imágenes**. He probado el archivo con una ruta de imagen correcta y la misma se muestra.

Comment: pero cuál problema?. La verdad es que no sé que problema pudiera haber, ya que yo estoy copiando la ruta de la ubicación del archivo para evitar errores y me sigue pasando eso. ¿Qué tipo de ruta has usado, relativa o absoluta?

Comment: El problema aquí por ejemplo: `<img src="C:\Users\wapg2\OneDrive\Escritorio\curso HTML5\Imágenes de las páginas web\Octava.jpeg"/>` Si no se ve la imagen es porque la ruta no es correcta. Prueba primero con una ruta absoluta y cuando funcione entonces te preocupas por aplicar una política de directorios en tu aplicación, mediante definición de constantes para las rutas o de otro modo. La cuestión aquí no es si relativo o absoluto, primero hay que encontrar el error y creo que es un error de rutas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilices rutas en PHP, intenta siempre que sean rutas relativas, no absolutas.

Siempre que puedas, incluye las imágenes que vayas a usar en una carpeta `img` dentro de la raíz de tu proyecto (donde tengas tu `index.php`).

Eso te ahorrará bastantes quebraderos de cabeza. Por otro lado, cuando yo utilizo rutas en PHP, lo hago siempre con barras (`C:/`) en vez de contrabarras (`C:\`). Quizá es una costumbre mía de trabajar con servidores Linux, pero no recuerdo que me den problemas en Windows. Cuando hayas hecho esto, puedes llamar a las imágenes con `<img src="/ruta_de_la_imagen/imagen.jpg"/>`.

Probablemente eso solucione el problema. También aclararte que, si bien es cierto que para ejecutar código PHP debes incluir las etiquetas especiales de apertura y cierre, sólo tienes que hacerlo cuando vayas a utilizar código PHP. Yo todo lo que veo en tu archivo es HTML puro, así que no se requeriría a priori.

Como podrás ver en las imágenes, tu código está perfecto tal y como está y el resultado es el esperado, al menos en mi equipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ya probé lo que me dijiste y sigue igual, sera que no se pueden insertar imágenes en php tal y como se hace en html?

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes probar es a simplificar las URLs. No uses espacios ni caracteres especiales. Nada de acentos/tildes ni eñes. Si necesitas separaciones en una URL usa guiones `-` o guiones bajos `_`.  
Tu elemento debería quedar así: `<img src="/img/octava.jpeg"/>`. Simple y fácil. No lo compliques más porque tienes más posibilidades de error.

Comment: Yo he probado tu código tal cual está pero con una imagen en mi equipo y va bien. ¿Si cambias el src por una URL de internet funciona?

Comment: No, ya le inserte una url al src de la etiqueta img y nada que funciona

Comment: También te diré que a veces hay cosas que en local no funcionan pero luego te lo llevas a un servidor real y sí que van. Las imágenes no deberían ser problema pero nunca se sabe. ¿Has probado a subirlo a algún servidor de pruebas online aunque sea gratuito?

Comment: No, podrías decirme cómo lo hago?

Comment: será que me puedes enviar una captura de cómo implementaste mí código, si no es mucha molestia?

Comment: Básicamente tienes que buscar un hosting online gratuito que te dará la posibilidad de hacer estas pruebas online. Mi recomendación es que busques un tutorial detallado o te metas cuando tengas tiempo. Uno de estos hostings gratuitos es [000webhost](https://es.000webhost.com) (antiguamente Hostinger). Te creas una cuenta, subes tu proyecto (imágenes incluidas) y accedes a una URL que te proporcionan para ver el resultado. A veces puedes escoger tú una parte de la URL, pero si quieres cambiarla entera y obtener más espacio, velocidad o funciones, ya es cuando empieza a costar dinero.

Comment: Te adjuntaré unas capturas en otra respuesta, pero verás que tu código está exactamente igual

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo

Comment: Por sugerencia del moderador te dejo las imágenes en esta misma respuesta. Soy muy novato en StackOverflow y no sé ni cómo responder bien todavía jajaja.